# llvm - get label of br instruction

Tags: label, llvm, branch, llvm-ir, llvm-3.0

My question is simple. Given an instruction of type branch, how do I extract the label out of it?
For example:

```
br label %while.cond
```

Should give me while.cond

```
br label %while.end
```

Should give me while.end

```
br i1 %cmp1, label %if.then, label %if.end
```

Should give me if, if.then, if.end respectively.

Comment: `inst->getOperand(0)`?

Comment: I tried that. It returns the condition in cases where it exists and when it doesn't, like in %if.end, it returns the whole basic block.

Answer (score 0):

First check `inst->isConditional()`, then access `inst->getOperand(1)` and `inst->getOperand(2)` in case it is true and `inst->getOperand(0)` if it is false.

The whole BasicBlock is what `BranchInst` actually accepts. If you want `%if.then` line, then call `getName()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code segment to get all the above information that you have asked.

```
 if (inst->getNumSuccessors() == 1)     
     return; //indicates not a branching instruction 

 unsigned int i; 

  for (i = 0; i <= inst->getNumSuccessors(); i++) {       

      llvm::outs() << inst->getOperand(i)->getName(); 

  }
```

Comment: Note that inst->getOperand(2)->getName() gives the %if.then and inst->getOperand(1)->getName() gives the %if.end label.